# Convert a vector to a matrix by counting repetitions

Tags: r

I´m using R.

I have a vector like this:

```
x <- c("P1","P1,P2","P1,P3","P2","P2,P3","P2","P1","P1,P3")
```

What I expect as output is a 3x3 triangular (or symmetric) matrix like this:

```
  P1 P2 P3
P1 2  1  2
P2    2  1
P3       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `levs` with the levels, i.e. P1, P2, P3, and then create factors with those levels for the first and second components.  Finally use `table`.

```
levs <- sort(unique(scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)))
x1 <- factor(sub(",.*", "", x), levs)
x2 <- factor(sub(".*,", "", x), levs)
table(x1, x2)
```

giving:

```
    x2
x1   P1 P2 P3
  P1  2  1  2
  P2  0  2  1
  P3  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp = sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))
t(sapply(tmp, function(s1) sapply(tmp, function(s2){
    sum(x == paste(unique(c(s1, s2)), collapse = ","))
})))
#   P1 P2 P3
#P1  2  1  2
#P2  0  2  1
#P3  0  0  0
```